# Linuxシステムを作る上で留意すべきセキュリティ事項

Tags: linux, security

諸事情が重なり、GentooLinuxを用いてLinuxデスクトップ環境をつくろうと考えています。

Linuxに触れてまだ日が浅いため、理解が浅いままネットワークにつなぐことに不安があります。

https://www.gentoo.org/doc/ja/security/security-handbook.xml
などのドキュメントはひと通り読んだのですが、内容が古かったりするため過信できません。

そのため、この場を借りて質問させていただこうと思いました。

求めるものとしては

- セキュアな環境にするのに便利なパッケージ
- 他のLinuxディストリビューターたちが構築する際に気をつけている点

などちょっとした事でも構いません。

大雑把な質問で恐縮ですが、皆さんの見解をいただけると幸いです。

Comment: セキュリティについて、なにか要求される/されているレベルとかありますか? もうちょっと、どのような用途で使うつもりなのか書いてあると、より良い解答が得られると考えられます。

Comment: 答えが1つに定まらない・自由な意見を聞く・どの回答も総じて有効となり得る質問は*避けるべき*とされています。質問の対象を狭めれば(`この用途のシステムにおけるiptablesでDROPするべきポート`のような)、よりよい質問になると思います。 [参考](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @KoRoN レベルとしては開発がとまったツールや非推奨なパッケージをなるべく回避することに専念しようと思っています。
例としてはifconfigを含むnet-toolsをUSEフラグを用いて無効にして、iproute2に置き換えたりなどです。
用途としてはプログラミングやブラウジング、サーバーの操作卓に使う程度です。

Comment: @TakumiSueda ご指摘ありがとうございます。
Linuxをインストールする過程でどの部分に不安があるのか、今一度整理してみます。

Answer (score 4):

「Linuxに触れてまだ日が浅い」と書かれてますので、知識を拡げる為のリソースを提示したほうが、役に立てるかもしれませんね。お門違いであればすみません…。

1. LPI-Japan Linuxセキュリティ標準教科書 （PDFは無料）
2. Linuxサーバーセキュリティ徹底入門 オープンソースによるサーバー防衛の基本 （書籍）